# Where can I find the upcoming DrupalCamps and DrupalCon?

Tags: community-official-site

Where can I find the upcoming DrupalCamps and DrupalCon ? I'm not aware of any website that contain information about  upcoming DrupalCamps and DrupalCon other than social media. I think will be nice if I can have a page where I can see upcoming DrupalCamps and DrupalCon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always enjoyed http://www.drupical.com/
It takes a direct feed from http://groups.drupal.org/events

Comment: I think http://www.drupical.com is the best place too look for drupal camps/cons because the map make everything so much easier to know where and when are you going. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [community pages](https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved) of drupal.org are probably a good starting point. From there you can find entry points [groups](https://groups.drupal.org/) and [events](https://groups.drupal.org/events) where local meetups, user group meetings, drupalcons etc. are announced and discussed. (You can even filter the event list by event type!)

Answer (score 1):

There is one page in drupal.org and they display the Upcoming DrupalCons and the past events with their official sites

[Drupalcon association page](https://assoc.drupal.org/drupalcon)

[Past DrupalCon](https://assoc.drupal.org/drupalcon/drupalcon-locations)

About drupal camps the domains drupalcamp.org and drupalcamp.com were donated by Noel Hidalgo to the Drupal Association.

[Archive of past drupalcamps](https://www.drupal.org/camp-archive)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking something like this page where it have all drupal camps and conference http://buildamodule.com/drupal-camps-calendar